# LESS modifyVars in nodejs

Tags: node.js, less

I'm trying to create from one LESS stylesheet, multiple css file, with different names according to a variable value.
The LESS modifyVars function seems to run only in a browser enviroment. So, Is possible to use the LESS modifyVars function in nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, `modifyVars` is available just in `browser.js` which is loaded (as the name suggests) just in the browser.

With node, we can achieve the same result by prepending a string containing the variables we wish to modify. Here a very short example:

```
var less = require('less');

var CSS = '.class { color: @color };';

['red', 'blue', 'yellow'].forEach(function(color, index){
  var settings = '@color: ' + color + ';';
  less.render(settings + CSS, function (e, css) {
    console.log('Script ' + index + ':')
    console.log(css);
    console.log('----')
  });
});
```

This should give you the same results as `modifyVars`.

Comment: This is a similar behavior but not the same (e.g.) It won't work with import or if @color was declared somewhere in the code. modifiyVars changes values within a parser enviroment. I can't find a way to get that env with node.